# Scrolling on reply url

Tags: bbpress, subscription, forum

I have installed BBPress and anonymus subscription plugins for my forum. The problem is, if a user recived an email that notify him that he recived a reply to his topic/answer, after he press on the button from that email to go on his question/answer, the page scroll to the end of the post not at the beginning. Is somebody who can help me with this

```
$reply_url     = bbp_get_reply_url( $reply_id );
<a style="padding:10px; text-decoration:none; background:#66BB6A; font-family: Open Sans; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; line-height: 20px; border-radius: 73px; color:white; letter-spacing: 1px; width:190px; display:block; text-align:center; " href="'.$reply_url.'">Read answer<a/>
```

This is a part from the code.
The link will be: [www.mysite.com/forum/questionName/#post-postNumber](http://www.mysite.com/forum/questionName/#post-postNumber)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the `#postNumber` part from the url, you can do something like this

```
$reply_url = explode('#', bbp_get_reply_url($reply_id))[0];
```

Comment: I still want the post number because I want to scroll to that reply. But I want the scroll to be 100-200 px upper. For example my posts are like this: avatar, author name, date bellow that is content and bellow content is apreciations and bellow is a border-bottom. Right now the page scroll to that border and I want the page to scroll to the avatar, author name and date.

Comment: Like in the above picture from question. I post a question and I add 3 answers and I recived 3 emails. If I click on the last email(from answer no 3) and click to the button the page will open and scroll to the answer no 3 but it will scroll to that border bottom and not to the name and the user will be confused because he must scroll a bit upper to see the content